# AngularJS does not translate correctly with translate-value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I got a small problem with my I18n integration.

AngularJS seems to skip one translation in the whole page. Everything translates fine except for one  tag.

I get my translations through JSON.

```
{
"password": {
    "title": "Wachtwoord voor [<b>{{username}}</b>]",
    "form": {
        "button": "Opslaan"
    },
    "messages": {
        "error":  "<strong>Er is een fout opgetreden!</strong> Het wachtwoord kon niet worden veranderd.",
        "success": "<strong>Wachtwoord veranderd!</strong>"
    }
}
}
```

The line in the HTML:

```
<h2 translate="password.title" translate-values="{username: '{{account.login}}'}">Password for [<b>{{account.login}}</b>]</h2>
```

This just displays `Password for [Admin]`.

The request for the password.json file contains exact the same as i stated above. The html contains this when inspected through the Chrome Console:

`<h2 translate="password.title" translate-values="{username: 'admin'}" class="ng-scope">Password for [admin]</h2>`

Everything else (Without those translate-values) translate fine. But this line doesnt. Why doesnt it work? The login name is correctly passed.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the translate directive, there is no need to add content inside the h2 tag. So, the following should work :

```
<h2 translate="password.title" translate-values="{username: '{{account.login}}'}"></h2>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Why does it work this way? Everywhere else i got text between the tags where i also use translation. Those work fine. But this doesnt. Thanks!

Comment: You can either assign value to the "translate" attribute or leave the attribute without value and add this value as text inside the HTML tag. Perhaps, in the rest working tags, you have inserted text, but not value to the "translate" attribute. You can also check http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api for the possible valid alternative expressions.